# Issue in adding .arr file to Android Binding Project in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am converting an app from Android to Xamain.Android. In my App i am using [Stepperindicator](https://github.com/badoualy/stepper-indicator) control with ViewPager.

Now i need to use same library in my Xamarin.Android project. I am new to Xamarin. When i search in Xamarin Docs, i can to know about [Xamarin.Android Java Binding Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/) where i can use my java libraries in xamarin.

I created a .arr file from Stepperindicator library project. In Xamarin I created Binding Library project and add my .arr file into that project and build it.

After adding binding library project to my android project I can access the functions in layout xml

> ```
> <com.badoualy.stepperindicator.StepperIndicator
>     android:id="@+id/stepperIndicator"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="20dp"
>     app:stpi_showStepNumberInstead="true" />
> ```

But when i can trying to access it in .cs file, i am not able in get the classes in library package. It saying error namespace not found even though i import the package.

Please help..

Comment: Although the intellisense may not work well for binding projects, you should be able to directly import the namespace and use the control directly. Can you upload a sample project showing what is not working in the `.cs` file?

Comment: How have you set the build actions correctly? Did you have to do any custom transforms?

Comment: i give build action as LibraryProjectZip and i don't have any custom transforms.